# Is centrosome one of the structures that red blood cells lose during maturation process?

Tags: cell-biology, organelle

Centrosomes are microtubule organising centres- their function is to facilitate cell division.

RBCs don't undergo division. They are produced via hematopoeisis in the bone marrow. It doesn't even have a nucleus, hence there is no use for centrosomes in mature RBCs and they probably don't have it.

I couldn't find any paper indicating this point. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

I was aware that mature red blood cells (RBCs) lose their nucleus, ER and Golgi apparatus. However, I wasn't sure about the centrosome! Centrosomes, being MTOCs (microtubule organising centers), have known functions beyond those in cell division. Some are cell type specific! **So be wary of thinking that all cells that do not undergo mitosis lack centrosomes.** I find it *flawed* to reason along the lines of

```
mature RBCs are anucleated cells =  no nucleus = no nuclear membrane = no mitosis = no mitotic spindle = no centrosomes
```

After a little research, I've found the following unreferenced statement in this opinion piece by [Rieder, Faruki & Khodjakov from 2001 in *Trends in Cell Biology*](https://www.cell.com/trends/cell-biology/comments/S0962-8924(01)02085-2):

> In some cells such as megakaryocytes, myocytes and **red blood cells of
> higher animals, the centrosome degenerates.** As a rule, however, such
> cells are terminally differentiated and no longer capable of entering
> the mitotic cycle.

If somebody finds a concrete example (or better yet, image!), that would be more convincing than an opinion piece.